# How to plot animated dots moving inside a circle?

Tags: python, python-3.x, animation, matplotlib, geometry

I'm trying to write a function that generates dots moving inside a circle. I already have a function that plots animated dots with matpltolib animation (thanks to Tony Babarino) but I'm having trouble writing the part that forces the dots to stay in the circle

That's how the part that genarates the movement works

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

# Initializing number of dots
N = 25


# Creating dot class
class dot(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 10 * np.random.random_sample()
        self.y = 10 * np.random.random_sample()
        self.velx = self.generate_new_vel()
        self.vely = self.generate_new_vel()

    def generate_new_vel(self):
        return (np.random.random_sample() - 0.5) / 5

    def move(self) :
            if np.random.random_sample() < 0.95:
                self.x = self.x + self.velx
                self.y = self.y + self.vely
            else:
                self.velx = self.generate_new_vel()
                self.vely = self.generate_new_vel()
                self.x = self.x + self.velx
                self.y = self.y + self.vely

# Initializing dots
dots = [dot() for i in range(N)]

# First set up the figure, the axis, and the plot element we want to animate
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 10), ylim=(0, 10))
d, = ax.plot([dot.x for dot in dots],
             [dot.y for dot in dots], 'ro', markersize=3)
circle = plt.Circle((5, 5), 1, color='b', fill=False)
ax.add_artist(circle)


# animation function.  This is called sequentially
def animate(i):
    for dot in dots:
        dot.move()
    d.set_data([dot.x for dot in dots],
               [dot.y for dot in dots])
    return d,

# call the animator. 
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=200, interval=20)

plt.show()
```

I want to improve the function move by adding a part that force the dots to saty in the circle
**I want the borders of the circle to be like a fence that the dots cannot cross**

I know how to detect when a dot crosses the line but I don't know what to do after that.

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: You need to clarify what you want to happen when a point hits the border of the circle: does it bounce back? Stay there? Reappear on the other side? In any case, the central idea is that you need to enforce the circle constraint: `x**2 + y**2 < R**2`

Comment: The dot is supposed to bounce back

Comment: Then you could simply invert the sign of the velocity (both components). Since your circle does not have its center in the origin, in this case the equation is slightly different: `(x - xc)**2 + (y - yc)**2 < R**2`, when this condition is true, the point is inside the circle having center in xc, yc and radius R.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have tried this but it doesn't work really well, sometimes the dot get stuck around the border of the circle and starts to vibrate it's weird.

Comment: And if I let the code run for a long time, several points manage to escape I don't understand why

Comment: Not sure, without seeing and running the code, but it has probably to do with how the bouncing is implemented. I just gave you an outline, not a complete solution.

Comment: Yes I have just put the following condition at the end of the move function. Do you think there is something to add ?                                               `if ((self.x-5)**2 +    (self.y-5)**2)>=1 :
                self.velx=self.velx*(-1)
                self.vely=self.vely*(-1)`

Comment: In the initialization code, you must make sure that all generated points start within the circle. Then the circle should be an initialization argument for the class. Even better would be to separate the concept of dot and that of an environment, a simple "physics" engine that operates on the dots. A better bouncing condition, that would likely prevent the "vibrating" issue is to calculate the direction of bounce on a tangent line to the circle at the point were your particle hits it and maybe add a little randomness to the bounce.

Comment: Okay thanks for your help I'm gonna look in that direction

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code so that you wouldn't have the problems of vibarting and escaping the circle. Every point that enters the circle doesn't escape (the points can be outside of the circle at start) nor vibrate on the edge of the circle.
    import numpy as np
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib import animation

```
# Initializing number of dots
N = 25
XC = 5
YC = 5
R = 1
R_SQR = R **2

# Creating dot class
class dot(object):
    def __init__(self, ind):
        self.x = 10 * np.random.random_sample()
        self.y = 10 * np.random.random_sample()
        self.velx = self.generate_new_vel()
        self.vely = self.generate_new_vel()
        self.in_circle = not self.calc_out_of_circle()

    def generate_new_vel(self):
        return (np.random.random_sample() - 0.5) / 5

    def move(self) :
        if np.random.random_sample() < 0.95:
            self.check_out_of_circle()
            self.x += self.velx
            self.y += self.vely
        else:
            self.velx = self.generate_new_vel()
            self.vely = self.generate_new_vel()
            self.check_out_of_circle()
            self.x += self.velx
            self.y += self.vely
        self.check_inside_circle()

    def calc_out_of_circle_with_params(self, x, y):
        return (x - XC) ** 2 + (y - YC) ** 2 >= R_SQR ** 2

    def calc_out_of_circle(self):
        return self.calc_out_of_circle_with_params(self.x, self.y)

    def check_out_of_circle(self):
        if self.in_circle and self.calc_out_of_circle_with_params(self.x + self.velx, self.y + self.vely):
            self.velx = -self.velx
            self.vely = -self.vely

    def check_inside_circle(self):
        if not self.calc_out_of_circle():
            self.in_circle = True


# Initializing dots
dots = [dot(i) for i in range(N)]

# First set up the figure, the axis, and the plot element we want to animate
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 10), ylim=(0, 10))
d, = ax.plot([dot.x for dot in dots],
             [dot.y for dot in dots], 'ro', markersize=3)
circle = plt.Circle((XC, YC), R, color='b', fill=False)
ax.add_artist(circle)


# animation function.  This is called sequentially
def animate(i):
    for dot in dots:
        dot.move()
    d.set_data([dot.x for dot in dots],
               [dot.y for dot in dots])
    return d,

# call the animator.
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=200, interval=20)
# plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```